# Where can I download Google Maps 5.0?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps 5.0 looks like a great upgrade, with offline maps and 3D. However, I can't find it in the market. The direct download link on Google does't work as well.

Do you know where I can download it directly?

Comment: Did you try appbrain.com or slideme.org?

Comment: @gary - not working. Since I already have maps installed, appbrains  doesn't allow me to download it. I also can't uninstall maps.

Comment: So your google maps app doesn't show that an update is available? Are you sure it wasn't allowed to auto-update and you already have it? :P Out of curiosity what phone are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably not in the US, right? Seems that Google Maps 5.0 is not yet available in many countries (just like Google Reader for Android). Meanwhile, you can use a link to the .apk file here: http://thegadgets.net/technology-news/download-google-maps-5-0-apk/

Download the apk file, copy to the SD card, and open with e.g. Linda File Manager. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in Israel. Thanks for the link, the new app looks amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I just successfully downloaded the update from the Android market:

- http://appaware.org/app/com.google.android.apps.maps
- http://www.zdnet.com/blog/cell-phones/google-maps-50-rolls-out-for-android-with-3d-and-offline-mapping/5145?utm_campaign=Android+-+Google+News&utm_medium=Twitter&utm_source=SNS.analytics